# UIKeyboard - turn off caps lock key

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone application, I want to turn off the caps lock key when my uikeyboard is shown.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Any UI control that conforms to the [UITextInputTraitsProtocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits) has a property called autocapitalizationType. Setting this to autocapitalizationTypeNone, either in code or via Interface Builder, will prevent the caps lock key being active when the keyboard for that element is shown.